# Confused about the application design (app architect?)

Tags: react-native, heroku, web-applications

So I'm building a mobile application and I've hit a wall as I'm confused about where everything fits or how things communicate with one another. Let me expand on that

Parts:

- mobile app (React Native)
- local storage (Redux-presist)
- cloud storage (AWS)
- backend admin UI that submitted information gets push to all the mobile apps (say there is a new workout or equipment added) (React)
- Database (Heroku-postgresql)
- API (I know I need one but that's it)

This is a chart that I have so far but I believe the Web app (admin UI) is left out of it (posted below). I'm going to ask the question simply without expanding on what's I've research to keep the confusion to the minimum.

1. How will the admin UI send the updated items to all of the mobile app?
2. How does the mobile app connect to postgresql on Heroku?
3. How does web application (admin UI) connect to postgresql on Heroku?
4. What is the client library?
5. What is the definition that connects to the service?
6. Does the API only fit into the mobile end of the application (is this node or express js)?
7. I know I need Node or express JS but I don't know if they are used on both end or just one?

**I know these are basic questions but I've confused myself and I would appreciate any guidance.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this explanation will help...

First you need 3 'computers':

1. The first computer is the mobile phone on which your app is running
2. The second computer is your central server which is running NodeJS/Express
3. The third computer is running your database.

For your app to work, you will need to 'wire-up' all three computers to 'talk' to each other. For communication between the mobile app and your server I suggest using simple HTTP to handle communication using the Fetch API `.fetch()`.

As far as your database is concerned, the mobile phone isn't going to be 'talking' to the database at all. All communication with the database will be handled by your server. For example, if you need some information from the database your NodeJS/Express sever will query the database using a database driver/library and then send that information back to the phone. (Note, sometimes people run the database on the same machine as NodeJS/Express, but often times the database will be running on it's own machine.)

Last, don't worry about 'pushing information from the server to the phone.' Instead, try to follow this pattern. The phone asks the server for some information, the server asks the database for the answer, the server then responds to the phone completing the HTTP request. The whole process looks something like this: The mobile app makes a `.fetch()` request, and the server responds with an answer. As far as the phone is concerned, it doesn't need to know that the database exists. And as far as the database is concerned, it doesn't need to know that the phone exists.

If you find yourself struggling, I suggest picking up a book on NodeJS and Express and dabbling with a little full stack web development. The example web apps that you build will either have the server 'spit out' HTML or JSON data. For your mobile app, you will need to spit out JSON. After you get up and running with NodeJS/Express, you can swap out your web app for your mobile app.

I hope my answer helps get you pointed in the right direction. There are a lot of moving parts involved with building a full stack app and none of it is really self explanatory.